# Object oriented programming main ideas

Tags: oop

Which of the following is NOT a part of Object-Oriented Programming?

- behaviors
- classes
- components
- procedures
- properties

Comment: Please try to demonstrate some effort when bringing us your homework questions. What have you tried? What are you not understanding? Can you eliminate any of these choices yourself?

Comment: @ZacCrites i know that classes is a part of oop

Comment: @ZacCrites can you please help me through explaining the others

Comment: Edit your question with your reasons for or against the other options.

Comment: @user3808597 Classes aren't an essential part of OOP, factory objects could replace them. Rather, classes are a type system for OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2016/cs303/lectures/oop.html) article:

> behaviors

Determined by how the object acts or reacts to requests (messages) from other objects

> classes

It's an object

> components

Polymorphism: substitute variables or objects of one type with variables or objects of another type. Polymorphism gives us the ability to switch components without loss of functionality.

<strike>procedures</strike>

> properties

They are the information stored by the class